# После первого ввода вылетает программа

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

class List {
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io. IOException {
FileReader fr = new FileReader("qwerty.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
  char choice,ignore; 
  for (;;) {

    do {
      System.out.println("Choose one (q to quit) ");
      choice = (char) System.in.read();
      do {
        ignore = (char) System.in.read();
      } while (ignore != '\n');

    } while (choice < '1' | choice > '2' & choice != 'q');
    if (choice == 'q') break;
    switch (choice) {
      case '1':
      int i = 1;
      while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(i + " : " + scan.nextLine());
        i++;
    }
      break;
      System.out.println();
      fr.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Короче,когда я нажимаю "1" выводиться текст,после того как я один раз нажал цифру "1" список больше не выводиться.Мне приходиться выходить из программы и заново в нее входить,чтобы вывести текст.Что делать,чтобы мне не приходилось выходить из программы и я мог вывести текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class List {
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

    Scanner scan;
    char choice, ignore;

    for (; ; ) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Choose one (q to quit) ");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("qwerty.txt");
            scan  = new Scanner(fr);
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
            do {
                ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while (ignore != '\n');

        } while (choice < '1' | choice > '2' & choice != 'q');
        if (choice == 'q') break;

        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                int i = 1;
                while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(i + " : " + scan.nextLine());
                    i++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ты используешь `Scanner` и на второй раз, когда ты считываешь строки через него, он уже находится на конце файла и поэтому ничего тебе не выводит, т.к. ничего не прочитал. Тебе нужно [сбросить позицию потока в файле](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787727/how-to-reset-filereader-in-java-without-having-to-change-my-program-drastically) и создать новый `Scanner`.